# ODOO : Cómo sumo a un field.Date() dias? así "2020-05-06"+2 dias="2020-05-08"

Tags: python, odoo

**He intentado con:**

```
fecha_prox      =  datetime.strptime(str(self.fecha_ejec), '%Y-%m-%d')
fecha_prox      = fecha_prox + timedelta(days=2)
```

pero el problema es que la función strptime  detecta como vacío `self.fecha_ejec` por alguna razón.
Luego para asegurarme que es un `string` lo hice `split` y lo junte como cadena pero  sale igual.
Lo curioso  es que si lo muestro en otro campo el valor de `self.fecha_ejec` si muestra.
nomas cuando es parámetro en `strptime` sale **`false`**

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código, aquí funciona paa mirar tanto días alante y días para atras, en la parte de `days = 1` especificas el numeor de días que quieres ver.

```
from datetime import date
import datetime

hoy = date.today()
hoy = hoy.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
ayer = datetime.datetime.strptime(hoy, "%Y/%m/%d") - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
ayer = ayer.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
manana = datetime.datetime.strptime(hoy, "%Y/%m/%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
manana = manana.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

al parecer te falta el datetime antes de timedelta